# Can Sonatype Nexus be configured to restrict which artifacts a user can deploy?

Tags: maven, nexus

I have installed Nexus 2.0.6 and the integration with my LDAP server is working (authentication only). Is there a way to configure Nexus so that only a set of developers are able to deploy a given artifact, or group?

I basically do not want a developer in Team A deploying an artifact that Team B is reponsible for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may partition a repository using repository targets, privileges, and roles as described [in this Sonatype blog post](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/02/how-to-partition-nexus-repositories-targets-privileges-and-roles/).  I tested this a few months back and it seemed to work well.

Answer (score 2):

Under Nexus 2.0.1, this is the solution that I've worked through and verified.

Caveats:  
This allows one to restrict the "Artifact Upload" option to a directory hierarchy.
This is not quite the same as "deploy" or in conjunction with "release prepare".

Steps:

1. Remove the single privilege of "Artifact Upload" from all that presently have it, that you do not want to have it.
2. Create the "Repository-Target" that includes the directory mask of where you want to give access.  Ex.  `.*/com/mycompany/target-dir/.*`    
     Double check the mask, it starts with period-asterisk AND ends with period-asterisk.
3. Create the "Repository-Privilege" that maps to the Repository-Target you just created.  Typically I include the repo-name in this repository-privilege-name, like "releases.com.mycompany.target-dir".  This creates the CRUD entries (4) for said directory.
4. Next, create the "Role" based on the Repository Privileges you just created (4), **plus** "Artifact Upload".   Total of 5 entries for the role.  Use the "Apply Filter" here to help you find these items. I name this role something like "Upload.Role.Releases.Target-Dir".   Again, when finished there should be 5 entries for this role:
   Artifact Upload  
    
   com.mycompany.target-dir(create)  
    
   com.mycompany.target-dir(delete)    
    
   com.mycompany.target-dir(read)    
    
   com.mycompany.target-dir(update)    
   This is what constrains the upload role to this repo.directory.
5. Create the User if it does not already exist, assign password.
6. Give the user the following Roles:  
   Nexus Deployment  
   Repo:  All Maven Repositories(Read)  
   UI: Base UI Privileges  
   Upload.Role.Relases.Target-Dir

Hit save and you've got it.  Later on, you can use this same approach to create a new Role for other repos (say Snapshot or 3rd Party), and keep the same directory mask.